# How to add multiple table of contents to R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using `bookdown` to knit together a technical report.
I'd like to have a table of contents for the overall document. I'd also like to have another table of contents of the appendix starting at the end of the document.
How do I input 2 tables of contents?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to make a bit of an example, including what type of document you're knitting to

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do that.

The **first table of contents** will be created with a default function.

How it looks:

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
---
```

If we want to make **the second table of contents** - we should use an additional R-Script from Github.
You can download it [there](https://gist.github.com/gadenbuie/c83e078bf8c81b035e32c3fc0cf04ee8).

And find more info and example [there](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/add-a-generated-table-of-contents-anywhere-in-rmarkdown/).

It is cool, you can place it everywhere.

**An illustration:**

[image]

Here are two **snags**, which I have found:

- a) The second, custom ToC will displayed in the first.
- b) The custom ToC hasn't page numbers after knitting to PDF.

---

**An addition:**
Check these LaTeX-solutions:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs

Comment: Thanks you so much! I actually tried this and it worked out great. However, I should've clarified that I need something that more closely resembles the default ToC formatting in Word. Something like "Section 1 ................. 1" that has page numbers.

Comment: @marin343 Maybe... then you should make a screenshot of the first ToC and after paste like a pic where you want?

Comment: @marin343 ... and look an addition